# Can I perform a transaction across two different MySQL databases on two different servers in different tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have a table A in database db1 in server A and table B in database db2 in server B, both of which are MySQL.

Is it possible to make a transaction, where updates in both tables are involved?

```
                      +-> Server A | db1 | table A -+
Transaction:  Update -+                             + -> COMMIT / ROLLBACK
                      +-> Server B | db2 | table B -+
```

If so, kindly provide step by step instruction on how to achieve this.

Comment: You want an application to connect to 2 different servers or one server connects to another? if first - it seems possible (assume the connection will not break), if second - the answer is "no".

Comment: federated engines

Comment: @AnkitKapoor Transactions are not supported for `FEDERATED Engine`. [proof](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html)

Comment: [_blog on XA_](http://mysqlha.blogspot.com/2008/07/do-you-really-want-to-use-xa-with-mysql.html) by a MySQL guru.  (Caveat: It was written in 2008.)

Comment: @Akina Correct .

Answer (score 3):

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597880/mysql-transaction-over-two-databases-on-different-servers) question. It seems like this is a possibility with InnoDB as your engine, but other than that, unfortunately, it does not seem like there is a way. This also seems dependent on the version of MySQL, like 5.6 and above, the thread I linked to points to a documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xa.html).

A side note: just because this seems to a possibility, it may not be the best solution. It seems that it would be best to write the transaction, and use a script to run the transaction on both servers.